# Determine target framework inside a visual studio code analyzer (Roslyn)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I have written a code analyzer (nothing fancy, based on the standard boilerplate code from Microsoft) that helps our teams with the migration of a framework based on classic .Net that has been ported to .net core.  The framework works in net452, net47, netstandard2.0 and .netcoreapp2.2.  Some of the messages emitted by the analyzer only make sense for certain versions of this framework.  Therefore I would like to know that target framework of the code I am currently analyzing.  Can this be done and if so, how ?

tx,
W

Comment: What do you mean "inside a visual studio code analyzer"? From the analysis results in "Error List"?

Answer (score -1):

If you're referring to how you tell which framework the warning is from, it's in brackets in the "Project" column of the "Error List" window:

[image: Error List view]

Or if you have conditional compilation, and you want to change the framework of the code you're viewing, you can change it at the top of the file view here:

[image: Target Framework]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear.  I am actually writing a code analyzer, that is the thing that fills the first picture you show.  Inside the code of this analyzer I would like to know the target framework of the code I am analyzing.44

Comment: So when viewing your code (which is targeting multiple frameworks), can you not see the dropdown box shown in the 2nd picture?

Comment: I am familiar with the dropdown when developing multi-target code.  However, a code analyser is written against .Net standard 1.3 only.  That's because it will *running* inside visual studio (through installatio with a vsix or a nuget).  I am looking for something inside the roslyn class zoo that can give me the target framework criterion.

Comment: I think updating your question to include that information (`I am looking for something inside the roslyn class zoo that can give me the target framework criterion`), would be helpful then! :)

Comment: Ok, tx.  I did it (I think).  Tx for you willingness to help so far.